# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics", referenced from objc-class-ref in libRNFirebase.a(RNFirebaseAnalytics.o)

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-signin, react-native-firebase

=> I have tried to add $(inherite) in other linkers flag. But still not woking.

=> Also tried to link some other solutions related to pods installation. As like

I am using firebase for push notification, My app contains google login and facebook login as well.

pods:

```
pod 'Firebase','4.2.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core','4.2.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging','4.2.0'

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRNFirebase.a(RNFirebaseAnalytics.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalyticsConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRNFirebase.a(RNFirebaseAnalytics.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRNFirebase.a(RNFirebase.o)
      objc-class-ref in libRNFirebase.a(RNFirebaseUtil.o)
      objc-class-ref in libRNFirebase.a(RNFirebaseMessaging.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRInstanceID", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRNFirebase.a(RNFirebaseInstanceId.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRMessaging", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRNFirebase.a(RNFirebaseMessaging.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRNFirebase.a(RNFirebase.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I'm still experiencing this issue, did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: i am having same issue , any workaround for same ?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I had to manually enable iOS Static Frameworks for RNFirebase on the project. To do that, add the following global to the top of your `/ios/Podfile` file:

```
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
```

References:

- https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3193#issuecomment-816101496
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7566#issuecomment-790110617
- https://rnfirebase.io/#allow-ios-static-frameworks